# PHP translate words in sentense

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have MYSQL database with 3 rows

```
ID   Num    Text 

id=1 Num=11 Text=Monday
id=2 Num=12 Text=John
```

In html i have two textarea and submit button.

```
<textarea name="1" >12 finished on 11</textarea>
```

on submit button click i want to copy this text in second textarea and change "11" on monday and "12" on John from database.
Changed text must look like

```
John finished on Monday.
```

Comment: So what is your question? How extract numbers from string? How to query database? Something else?

Comment: how to extract values from mysql and chage it in string

Comment: `select * from table`

Comment: and also how to find in string "12 finished on 11" 12 and 11 to change.

Comment: `echo str_replace([11,12], ['Monday', 'John'], '12 finished on 11')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a getter function that accepts Num and returns Text.

```
function getText($num){
//connect database
//query table - select Text from table_name WHERE Num = $num
return text
}

<textarea name="1" ><?php echo getText(12) . ' finished on ' . getText(11);?></textarea>
```

Comment: i have another question. it works. how can i change this script to find all Num   in string and change it with Text. e.g gettext('12 finished on 11 at 10:00, 14 finished on 14 at 17:00 , 12 finished on 19 at 14:00') changes all 12 to John and all 11 on Monday

Comment: Where do you get 12 .... 11 at ..., 14 ..... 14 at .... May be if you give some information about where you get those numbers it will be much more easier

Comment: I am asking this because may be writing a sql to join tables would be the best bet here, of course if 11s, 12s are in another table.

Comment: there is two sql table. 11 12 are in the second table. in first there are a lot of rows. one of them is row "finish" and in "finish" there are these ('12 finished on 11 at 10:00, 14 finished on 14 at 17:00 , 12 finished on 19 at 14:00')

Comment: also there is a second row "text" with some information. and in this text there are some specific words or numbers to change like i explained

Comment: just put column names and a sample data from both tables, please. Then you can figure out join sql and do it in a better way

Comment: i have added pictures of column names and data